# Cloudfront to use different Content-Type for compressed and uncompressed files

Tags: svg, amazon-s3, content-type, amazon-cloudfront

I am serving a website generated by a static site generator via S3 and Cloudfront. The files are being uploaded to S3 with correct Content-Types. The DNS points to Cloudfront which uses the S3 bucket as its origin. Cloudfront takes care about encryption and compression. I told Cloudfront to compress objects automatically. That worked fine until I decided to change some of the used images from PNG to SVG.

Whenever a file is requested as uncompressed it is delivered as is with the set Content-Type (image/svg+xml) and the site is rendered correctly. However, if the file is requested as compressed it is delivered with the default Content-Type (application/octet-stream) and the image is missing in the rendering. If I then right-click on the image and choose to open the image in a new tab, it will be shown correctly (without the rest of the page).

The result is the same independent of the used browser. In Firefox I know how to set it to force requesting compressed or uncompressed pages. I also tried curl to check the headers. These are the results:

```
λ curl --compressed -v -o /dev/null http://dev.example.com/img/logo-6998bdf68c.svg
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x20049798; line 1090 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 52.222.157.200...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x20049798; line 1143 (connection #0)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to dev.example.com (52.222.157.200) port 80 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x20049798; line 1240 (connection #0)
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x20049798; line 1258 (connection #0)
> GET /img/logo-6998bdf68c.svg HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.44.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x20049798; line 1337 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x20049798; line 1464 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x20049798; line 1474 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 7468
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 13:31:33 GMT
< x-amz-meta-cb-modifiedtime: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 13:28:26 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 13:30:24 GMT
< ETag: "6998bdf68c8812d193dd799c644abfb6"
* Server AmazonS3 is not blacklisted
< Server: AmazonS3
< X-Cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 36c13eeffcddf77ad33d7874b28e6168.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: jT86EeNn2vFYAU2Jagj_aDx6qQUBXFqiDhlcdfxLKrj5bCdAKBIbXQ==
<
{ [7468 bytes data]
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x20049798; line 1632 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
100  7468  100  7468    0     0  44526      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 48493
* Connection #0 to host dev.example.com left intact
* Expire cleared
```

and for uncompressed it looks better:

```
λ curl -v -o /dev/null http://dev.example.com/img/logo-6998bdf68c.svg
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x20049798; line 1090 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 52.222.157.203...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x20049798; line 1143 (connection #0)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to dev.example.com (52.222.157.203) port 80 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x20049798; line 1240 (connection #0)
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x20049798; line 1258 (connection #0)
> GET /img/logo-6998bdf68c.svg HTTP/1.1
> Host: dev.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.44.0
> Accept: */*
>
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x20049798; line 1337 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x20049798; line 1464 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x20049798; line 1474 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: image/svg+xml
< Content-Length: 7468
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 20:56:11 GMT
< x-amz-meta-cb-modifiedtime: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 20:39:17 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 20:41:13 GMT
< ETag: "6998bdf68c8812d193dd799c644abfb6"
* Server AmazonS3 is not blacklisted
< Server: AmazonS3
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Cache: RefreshHit from cloudfront
< Via: 1.1 ac27d939fa02703c4b28926f53f95083.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: AlodMvGOKIoNb8zm5OuS7x_8TquQXzAAXg05efSMdIKgrPhwEPv4kA==
<
{ [2422 bytes data]
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x20049798; line 1632 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
100  7468  100  7468    0     0  27667      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 33639
* Connection #0 to host dev.example.com left intact
```

I don't want to switch off the compression for performance reasons. And it looks that this only happens for SVG file types. All other types have the correct, ie. the same Content-Type. I already tried to invalidate the cache and even switched it off completely by setting the cache time to 0 seconds. I cannot upload a compressed version when uploading to S3 because the upload process is automated and cannot easily be changed for a single file.

I hope that I did something wrong because that would be easiest to be fixed. But I have no clue what could be wrong with the setting. I already used Google to find someone having a similar issue, but it looks like it's only me. Anyone, who has an idea?

Comment: I thought about this being the issue. But I do not compress. Cloudfront does all the compressing and the compressed files are not stored on S3. They are for the cache time stored in the Cloudfront edges. Cloudfront compresses if a client requests Content-Encoding: gzip, deflate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by forcing the MIME type to "image/svg+xml" instead of "binary/octet-stream" which was selected after syncing the files with python boto3.

When you right click on an svg in a S3 bucket you can check the mimetype by viewing the metadata:

[image]

I'm not sure if this was caused by the python sync, or by some weirdness in S3/Cloudfront. I have to add that just a cache invalidation didn't work after that. I had to re-upload my files with the correct mimetype to get cloudfront access to the svg working ok.

Answer (score 2):

You're misdiagnosing the problem.  CloudFront doesn't change the `Content-Type`.

CloudFront, however, does cache different versions of the same object, based on variations in the request.

If you notice, your `Last-Modified` times on these objects are different.  You originally had the content-type set wrong in S3.  You subsequently fixed that, but CloudFront doesn't realize the metadata has changed, since the ETag didn't change, so you're getting erroneous `RefreshHit` responses.  It's serving the older version on requests that advertise gzip encoding support.  If the actual payload of the object had changed, CloudFront would have likely already updated its cache.

Do an [invalidation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) to purge the cache and within a few minutes, this issue should go away.

Comment: I've the same issue: cache invalidation didn't solve it. SVG views fine in browser when downloaded standalone. Usage in html -> no pics